# Check if app code is out of date without version numbers

Tags: ios, git, version-control, continuous-integration

I am building test automation and continuous integration for our mobile apps, and I would like a way to detect if the app on the current device is out of date without using version numbers. Often times minor bug fixes and code changes are made without updating a version number, so if possible I would like to be able to compare the code behind the app on the device with the latest code in the local git repository, and if there are any differences rebuild the app with the code in the repository. Is there any way to do this?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where does the app on the device also located in a git repo or out of a git repo? If the app on the device out of git repo, you can not compare by commit, and it's usually compared by release versions.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Marina Liu.  I updated the question to clarify what I meant.  This might not be possible but I'm wondering if there is a way to basically extract the app code from the app currently installed on the device and compare it with the current code in the repository to detect if there are any differences.  The app on the device is installed using XCode build tools. 
 The code itself is stored in git.  Please see my edits above for a few more details.  Thanks.

Comment: I added the way to check if your local repo is out of date in below answer, you can have a try.

Comment: Can you check the local repo is out of date now?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the app out of date in local repo by the commands (assume the `origin` is the remote repo where your code push to):

```
git fetch
git log master..origin/master --oneline
```

- If there is no output for the command `git log master..origin master --oneline`, that means your local master is up to date.
- If there show commit(s) from the output of the command `git log master..origin master --oneline`, that means your local master branch is out of date. And the commit(s) list is the what your local repo non-exist.

And to check the difference between local repo and remote repo by:

```
git diff origin/master master
```

When you ready to update your local repo, just execute the command `git pull`.

Comment: That's a little different than what I was asking above, but also helpful for other purposes.  Thank you!